# What number of iterations must I take to reach zero in this way?

Tags: probability, random

Choose a number, say 100000.

- Choose any random number in the range $[0, 100000]$, say $n$.
- Choose a number in the range $[0, n]$ and set $n$ to this.
- Repeat this till $n$ is zero.

A quick Python script tells me that:

$10^4\;$ takes 9.822 iterations (on average).

$10^8 \; $ takes $18.981$.

$10^{12}$ takes $28.201$.

$10^{16}$ takes $37.496$.

$10^{20}$ takes $46.82$.

$10^{200}$ takes $460.922$ iterations to reach zero.

Interestingly, these numbers don't vary much from one run of the script to another.

Could anyone provide me with a mathematical explanation for this?

Comment: On average you're dividing the interval into half its size at each step. So it will on average take $\log_2 n$ iterations to reach zero. Hence why your $10^{200}$ time is approximately $10$ times the $10^{20}$ time.

Comment: Asymptotic value seems to indicate the factor is $e$ rather than $2$ as in milind's comment. Natural logarithms highly correlated with test values.

Comment: @Mark Bennet Yes, I was about to add the same thing. I find this strange; is there any explanation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $P_r$ be the mean number of steps from starting number $r$.

Then we have $$P_n=1+\frac 1 n\sum^{n-1}_0P_r$$ or $$nP_n=n+\sum^{n-1}_0P_r$$

Using the expressions for $nP_n$ and $(n-1)P_{n-1}$ we obtain:

$$nP_n -(n-1)P_{n-1}=n-(n-1)+P_{n-1}$$

Which simplifies to $$P_n-P_{n-1}=\frac1 n$$

Since $P_1=1$ we get the harmonic series, whose properties are well known.

Comment: Alternatively, we can obtain $P_n=P_{n-1}+\frac1n$ just as well from $P_n=\frac1{n+1}(1+P_n)+(1-\frac1n)P_{n-1}$: Either the first number is $n$ (with probability $\frac1{n+1}$) and hence we make one move and start over again; or the first number is $<n$ (with probability $1-\frac1n$) and hence the game continues just as if we had started with $n-1$.

Comment: @Mark could you explain the answer a bit? I thought I understood it, but...

Comment: The idea is that there are $n$ possible outcomes for the first "move" $\{0,1 \dots (n-1)\}$. So we have 1 for the first move plus the number of moves from the the place we move to.

Comment: At the end we have $P_n=\frac 1 n+P_{n-1}=\frac 1 n+\frac 1 {n-1}+P_{n-2}$ etc